# C#: GetCustomAttribute returns different instance?

Tags: c#, .net

Shouldn't `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(s)` return the same instance of `Attribute`? The following code appears it returns different instances:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AttributeNoShared
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private sealed class AnyAttribute : Attribute
        {
        }

        private sealed class AnyClass
        {
            [Any]
            public int AnyProperty { get; set; }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(AnyClass).GetProperty(nameof(AnyClass.AnyProperty));
            var result1 = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AnyAttribute>();
            var result2 = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AnyAttribute>();

            Assert.AreEqual(result1, result2);  // This succeeded
            Assert.IsTrue(object.ReferenceEquals(result1, result2), "Different instance of attribute"); // This failed
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? I'm expecting runtime `Attribute` to be shared because I would like to store some state in it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more straitforward to define a constructor for your attribute that takes the state you want to store as a parameter, then specify the value your storing in the attribute declaration?

Comment: @PaulKeister This is not the case. The attribute constructor only works with constant values, the state I want to store is a little bit more complex, for example, to store the relationship between two attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an error, that's by dessign. Attributes aren't instanced until they are requested. In order to return the same instance .net would need to create a cache for the attributes and that could lead to consume too much memory in some scenerios as these would need to be preserve during all the life of the process.

Anyways, you can always create static properties that are shared by all the instances. If you thought that there would be one instance of the attribute per each tagged property you can do something like this:

```
public class InformationAttribute : Attribute
{
    static Dictionary<string, object> storage = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    string propName;
    public InformationAttribute(string PropertyName)
    {
        propName = PropertyName;
    }

    public void SetValue(object Value)
    {
        storage[propName] = Value;
    }

    public object GetValue()
    {
        if(storage.ContainsKey(propName))
            return storage[propName];

        return null;
    }

}
```

and use like this:

```
private sealed class AnyClass
{
    [Information("AnyClass.AnyProperty")]
    public int AnyProperty { get; set; }
}

//...

var propertyInfo = typeof(AnyClass).GetProperty(nameof(AnyClass.AnyProperty));
var result = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AnyAttribute>();

if(result.GetValue() == null)
   result.SetValue(WhatEverYouWantToStore);
```